# Vim c++ indexing that differentiates between symbols with same names

Tags: vim, tags, ctags, cscope

I've been trying out vim with exuberant tags and cscope but when listing the usages of a variable it also lists variables with the same name that aren't really the symbol I'm looking at. For example if I want to jump to the declaration or other usages of a variable called "temp", it will give me all variables called "temp" in the whole repo. Am I using tags and cscope wrong or is there another plugin I should be using instead?

Comment: Yes, you're using tags wrong. You should read `:h definition-search` and `:h include-search` to learn the plethora of shortcuts to go to declarations and usages (also called "references"). ctags is a smarter tool in a way, but also more general.

Answer (score 0):

Ctags and cscope use parsers and even regular expressions to find symbols in files. They "understand" syntax, in a way, but they don't understand code so they have no idea about what specific function is called where.

Consequently…

- that relationship is not encoded in the resulting database,
- and it is lost to any program using ctags or cscope.

If you want a tool that knows exactly which `temp` is referenced, then you don't want csope or ctags. You want something based on a compiler, like clang.